# How can I build a new vector with specific data from two other different sized vectors using R

Tags: r

I have a vector which is a list of Brazilian states and I want to form a data.frame that tells which state is located in which region.

The data for the data frame will be imported from an website that doesn't necessarily has all the states listed, so, it will have to pick one state by one, and is going to be adjusted to its own region.

Then, I have 5 different region vectors with its own states.

```
states <-  c("AC", "AL", "AM", "AP", "BA", "CE", "DF", "ES", "GO", "MA", "MG", "MS", "MT", "PA", "PB", "PE", "PI", "PR", "RJ", "RN", "RO", "RR", "RS", "SC", "SE", "SP", "TO")

no <- c("AC","AP","AM","PA","RO","RR","TO")
su <- c("PR","SC","RS")
co <- c("GO","MG","MS","DF")
ne <- c("AL","BA","CE","MA","PB","PE","PI","RN","SE")
mges <- c("MG","ES")
rj <- c("RJ")
sp <- c("SP")
```

I need to have a program that loops the "states" vector from an website to form the data frame with the columns: "STATE" "REGION".

The hardest part is to pick a specific data from the vector to form a new one existing from region, since i'm importing data that doesn't actually has all the states.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend storing the region information in a list. This list can be used to create a data frame.

```
regions <- list(no = c("AC","AP","AM","PA","RO","RR","TO"),
                su = c("PR","SC","RS"),
                co = c("GO","MG","MS","DF"),
                ne = c("AL","BA","CE","MA","PB","PE","PI","RN","SE"),
                mges = c("MG","ES"),
                rj = c("RJ"),
                sp = c("SP"))

region_dat <- data.frame(state = unlist(regions),
                         region = rep(names(regions), lengths(regions)))
```

Now you can merge the `states` data and the data frame containing the region information:

```
merge(data.frame(state = states), region_dat)
```

The result:

```
   state region
1     AC     no
2     AL     ne
3     AM     no
4     AP     no
5     BA     ne
6     CE     ne
7     DF     co
8     ES   mges
9     GO     co
10    MA     ne
11    MG     co
12    MG   mges
13    MS     co
14    PA     no
15    PB     ne
16    PE     ne
17    PI     ne
18    PR     su
19    RJ     rj
20    RN     ne
21    RO     no
22    RR     no
23    RS     su
24    SC     su
25    SE     ne
26    SP     sp
27    TO     no
```

Comment: This code has worked perfectly! Thank you very much @Sven Hohenstein!!

Answer (score 0):

If are able to restructure your data a little here is a `tidyverse` way of doing what you want to do.

```
library(tidyverse)

df1 = data.frame(states = c("AC","AP","AM","PA","RO","RR","TO"), region='no')
df2 = data.frame(states = c("PR","SC","RS"), region='su')
df3 = data.frame(states = c("GO","MG","MS","DF"), region='co')
df4 = data.frame(states = c("AL","BA","CE","MA","PB","PE","PI","RN","SE"), region='ne')
df5 = data.frame(states = c("MG","ES"), region='mges')
df6 = data.frame(states = c("RJ"), region='rj')
df7 = data.frame(states = c("SP"), region='sp')

dfs = list(df1,df2,df3,df4,df5,df6,df7)

state_regions = bind_rows(dfs)
```

For each region create a dataframe with the associated states. Then combine all the data frame rows.

```
   states region
1      AC     no
2      AP     no
3      AM     no
4      PA     no
5      RO     no
6      RR     no
7      TO     no
8      PR     su
9      SC     su
10     RS     su
11     GO     co
12     MG     co
13     MS     co
14     DF     co
15     AL     ne
16     BA     ne
17     CE     ne
18     MA     ne
19     PB     ne
20     PE     ne
21     PI     ne
22     RN     ne
23     SE     ne
24     MG   mges
25     ES   mges
26     RJ     rj
27     SP     sp
```